# How to create a radio button parameters in the Birt reporting tool

Tags: birt

I have two radio button as ascending and descending order. When I click the ascending order radio button want to display the names in ascending order from the database.  How to connect the parameter with the database to fetch the data.

I have attached the code below,

Employee-Sorting:

```
<input type="radio" name="emp_sorting" value="emp_ascending" id="emp_ascending" 
       onkeyup="changeName();">
emp_ascending 
<input type="radio" name="emp_sorting" value="emp_descending" id="emp_descending"
       onkeyup="changeName();">
emp_descending
<a id="emp_name" href="">View</a><br><br> 

<script>
function changeName() {
    var input_value = document.getElementById("emp_ascending").value;
    var input_value1 = document.getElementById("emp_descending").value;
    var context_path = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";
    var create_href = context_path + "/frameset__report=report_sort.rptdesign&e_name=" 
                    + input_value +" &emp_‌​name=" + input_value1 
                    + "&__parameterpage=false" ;
    emp_name.href= create_href;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide us some code ?

Comment: I have attached the code below,Employee-Sorting::
<input type="radio" name="emp_sorting" value="emp_ascending" id="emp_ascending" onkeyup="changeName();">emp_ascending
<input type="radio" name="emp_sorting" value="emp_descending" id="emp_descending" onkeyup="changeName();">emp_descending 
<a id="emp_name" href="">View</a><br><br>

Comment: <script>function changeName()
{var input_value = document.getElementById("emp_ascending").value;
var input_value1 = document.getElementById("emp_descending").value;
var context_path = "<%=request.getContextPath()%>";
var create_href = context_path+"/frameset__report=report_sort.rptdesign&e_name="+input_value+"&emp_name="+input_value1+"&__parameterpage=false" ;
emp_name.href= create_href;}</script>

Answer (score 1):

You need a report parameter named for example "sort_order", handling the sort order separately from the employee name. In your code you actually plug radio button values to report parameters named "e_name" and "emp_name", which is not very helpful neither for you neither for us to understand what is going on with the sorting order.

Then, in the beforeOpen method of the dataset you can replace a default sort order with an expression like:

```
this.queryText=this.queryText.replace(" ASC"," "+params["sort_order"].value);
```

To prevent any SQLIA vulnerability, you should first check if params["sort_order"].value equals to "ASC" or "DESC:

```
 var sort=params["sort_order"].value;
 if (sort=="ASC" || sort=="DESC"){
    this.queryText=this.queryText.replace(" ASC"," "+sort);
 }
```

Though another approach would be much easier than radio buttons, without a single byte of client-side javascript: define native birt drillthrough actions on images representing ASC and DESC directions. See a live example [with this report](http://www.visioneo.org/tablet-economic-report), there is an image in columns header allowing to sort the table dynamically. This image is not shown in PDF export (birt "visibility" property).

[image]